# Should I worry about home routers support of RTCDataChannel?

Tags: webrtc, sctp, rtcdatachannel

RTCDataChannel is a part of WebRTC and is used for p2p messaging over SCTP.

I'm seeing some answers on stackoverflow where people mention growing browser support
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14539939/1267910

However, I'm wondering if browser support should be the main concern when using WebRTC, as it seems that the transport protocol it's running on (SCTP) is not handled very well by many home routers, which aren't getting updated as fast as some of the browsers are.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359410/1267910

Comment: WebRTC data channels use [SCTP over DTLS over UDP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20508055/918910), which means UDP packets are sent. There's also TURN TCP when nothing else will do.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!